# Lightweight source code beautifier

Tags: text-editors, file-format, source-code

I am looking for a lightweight PHP prettyprint (beautification) tool. In Netbeans, I can **Right-click** and select **Format** to format source code. Is there a text editor with the same capability?

Comment: *Format* as in fixing indenting and white space, or do you mean [syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting)?

Comment: is my question is stupid?

Comment: @iglvzx I means like right-click Format in NetBeans :)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a bit more as to what your aiming for?

Comment: @eureka Ah. So, the first definition I gave. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: FYI, code formatting and beautification is known as [prettyprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint). :)

Comment: @eureka Which programming or scripting language are you using? There might be better tools for different languages.

Comment: @iglvzx mainly PHP :D

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn which notepad++ plugin can I use for format identation and white space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Notepad++'s auto-indenter. It is in TextFX-> TextFX Edit->Reindent C++ code.

Comment: Question is for PHP pretty print...

Comment: Notepad++ cannot tell the difference. Indenting rules are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Many code beautifiers and prettyprint tools are hosted online. These online tools may be the best, as they are operating system independent. For **PHP**, some examples are [PHPFormatter.com](http://www.phpformatter.com/) and [PrettyPrinter.de](http://www.prettyprinter.de/). If you are looking for a stand-alone application, [phpCodeBeautifier](http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/) is available for both Windows and Linux.